# Why no compiler appears able to optimize this code?

Tags: c, optimization

Consider the following C code (assuming 80-bit `long double`) (note, I do know of `memcmp`, this is just an experiment):

```
enum { sizeOfFloat80=10 }; // NOTE: sizeof(long double) != sizeOfFloat80
_Bool sameBits1(long double x, long double y)
{
    for(int i=0;i<sizeOfFloat80;++i)
        if(((char*)&x)[i]!=((char*)&y)[i])
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

All compilers I checked (gcc, clang, icc on gcc.godbolt.org) generate similar code, here's an example for gcc with options `-O3 -std=c11 -fomit-frame-pointer -m32`:

```
sameBits1:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [esp+16]
        cmp     BYTE PTR [esp+4], al
        jne     .L11
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [esp+17]
        cmp     BYTE PTR [esp+5], al
        jne     .L11
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [esp+18]
        cmp     BYTE PTR [esp+6], al
        jne     .L11
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [esp+19]
        cmp     BYTE PTR [esp+7], al
        jne     .L11
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [esp+20]
        cmp     BYTE PTR [esp+8], al
        jne     .L11
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [esp+21]
        cmp     BYTE PTR [esp+9], al
        jne     .L11
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [esp+22]
        cmp     BYTE PTR [esp+10], al
        jne     .L11
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [esp+23]
        cmp     BYTE PTR [esp+11], al
        jne     .L11
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [esp+24]
        cmp     BYTE PTR [esp+12], al
        jne     .L11
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [esp+25]
        cmp     BYTE PTR [esp+13], al
        sete    al
        ret
.L11:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

This looks ugly, has branch on every byte and in fact doesn't seem to have been optimized at all (but at least the loop is unrolled). It's easy to see though that this could be optimized to the code equivalent to the following (and in general for larger data to use larger strides):

```
#include <string.h>
_Bool sameBits2(long double x, long double y)
{
    long long X=0; memcpy(&X,&x,sizeof x);
    long long Y=0; memcpy(&Y,&y,sizeof y);
    short Xhi=0; memcpy(&Xhi,sizeof x+(char*)&x,sizeof Xhi);
    short Yhi=0; memcpy(&Yhi,sizeof y+(char*)&y,sizeof Yhi);
    return X==Y && Xhi==Yhi;
}
```

And this code now gets much nicer compilation result:

```
sameBits2:
        sub     esp, 20
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [esp+36]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+40]
        xor     edx, DWORD PTR [esp+24]
        xor     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+28]
        or      edx, eax
        movzx   eax, WORD PTR [esp+48]
        sete    dl
        cmp     WORD PTR [esp+36], ax
        sete    al
        add     esp, 20
        and     eax, edx
        ret
```

So my question is: why is none of the three compilers able to do this optimization? It it something very uncommon to see in the C code?

Comment: Potential for undefined behaviour. `long double` is not required to have 10 bytes. What do you want to accomplish with that code? It looks obfuscated and like a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: @Olaf As I've already said, I assume this size due to the chosen target (Linux x86).

Comment: I vote up. As I explained below the question is about the optimization, not the consistency of code. And the compiler really seems unable to optimize it. Or simply the output is really the best optimization even if ugly to see.

Comment: Which is bad style. Never write such code without actual need. Use language features and writing full standard compliant portable code.

Comment: @Frankie_C: That way it is too broad. Not every question why some obscure construct is not optimised is useful or on-topic.

Comment: probably because no one added this as a pattern in the optomizer. generally, a sequence of cmp, jne in series should be replaced by xor, or in series. you can replace the first case with `char ret; for(int i=0;i<sizeof x;++i) ret |= ((char*)&x)[i]^((char*)&y)[i]; return !ret;`

Comment: @Olaf no one is required to write standard compliant (as in _completely_ generic) code for a single target. Otherwise one could just as easily chose another language and abstract away from the target.

Comment: @Ruslan: No, and you are very well allowed to rely on UB. But that does not make a comment obsolete warning potential other readers following this bad style. stack overflow is to **enhance** code quality, not degrade it. Even less if that is without actual need - what's wrong with `sizeof(x)` instead of `10`? Write this in a goo company and the seniours will instantly trash your code (or lint/etc might already complain).

Comment: @Olaf I could agree with you, but you cannot ignore the possibility that some code, similar to this, and maybe less obscure will produce the same assembler. Then the question will come up again in the same way: about the optimization, not the scope of code.

Comment: @Olaf easy: `sizeof(x)==12` on 32-bit x86 and `16` on 64-bit. In none of these cases does it equal 10. And comparing padding bytes will give wrong results.

Comment: @Frankie_C: Please read what comments are for. I did not **answer** and that would have just been a single comment if OP would not insist on justifying his flaw.

Comment: @Ruslan: And how do you know the used bits start from offset `0`?

Comment: @Olaf I rely on the ABI.

Comment: @Ruslan: Fair enough, I'll retract my objection about the magic number - partially. Using an explicit value seems to be justified, unless the compiler provides some built-in. But you should not have it hidden in the code, but use a `#define` instead. As an additional recommendation, this should be encapsulated in an ABI-abstraction module. The comment about the obfuscation stands, though.

Comment: @Olaf with this I agree, yes. The magic number was there to shorten the _example_ code. I've since added an enum to make its meaning more obvious.

Comment: Just a last comment: Using `enum`s that way can be cause for other trouble. While here your value is an `int` and no problem arises, this might not always be true. _enum-constants_, are **always** `int`, adding problems when using larger values.

Comment: @Ruslan: Compiler writers are not magicians. They are coders like you and me, who try to decide what's worth going after.

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, it is unable to do this optimization because you completely obfuscated the meaning of your code by overloading it with unduly amount of memory reinterpretation. A code like this justly makes the compiler react with "I don't know what on Earth this is, but if that's what you want, that's what you'll get". Why you expect the compiler to even bother to transform on kind of memory reinterpretation into another kind of memory reinterpretation (!) is completely unclear to me.

Secondly, it can probably be made to do it in theory, but it is probably not very high on the list of its priorities. Remember, that code optimization is usually done by a *pattern matching* algorithm, not by some kind of A.I. And this is just not one of the patterns it recognizes.

Most of the time your manual attempts to perform low-level optimization of the code will defeat compiler's effort to do the same. If you want to optimize it yourself, then go all the way. Don't expect to be able to start and then hand it over to the compiler to finish the job for you.

Comparison of two `long double` values `x` and `y` can be done very easily: `x == y`. If you want a bit-to-bit memory comparison, you will probably make the compiler's job easier by just using `memcmp` in a compiler that inherently knows what `memcmp` is (built-in, intrinsic function).

Comment: The comparison can be done very easily if you want a _floating-point comparison_. Not as easy if you want bit-for-bit comparison.

Comment: I can understand your point of view, but the question of OP is not about the consistency of code. It is rather on what is the reason that refrain the compiler from optimize the code, that is perfectly legal even if could appear ugly. Moreover the point made by Ruslan about the bits comparison could make some sense (the simple comparison of float values is always a problem). I think that the answer is simply that the unrolling of the `for` loop is the fastest code. Anyway PellesC doesn't unroll the loop and produce a code very close to the requested one.

Comment: Good the point about the `memcmp`. Even if the core of the question remains the strange optimization.

Comment: About `memcmp` I've noted in the OP that I do know of it, and deliberately chose not to use it for the sake of experiment. Also, none of the three compilers I tested seem to be able to inline `memcmp` (although icc calls `_intel_fast_memcmp` there).